# not able to start minikube on mac

Tags: minikube

I am trying to setup minikube on my mac machine

Below are environment:

```
nhs-MBP:~ anhtrang$ minikube version
minikube version: v0.26.1
anhs-MBP:~ anhtrang$ echo "";

anhs-MBP:~ anhtrang$ echo "OS:";
OS:
anhs-MBP:~ anhtrang$ cat /etc/os-release
cat: /etc/os-release: No such file or directory
anhs-MBP:~ anhtrang$ echo "";

anhs-MBP:~ anhtrang$ echo "VM driver":
VM driver:
anhs-MBP:~ anhtrang$ grep DriverName ~/.minikube/machines/minikube/config.json
    "DriverName": "virtualbox",
anhs-MBP:~ anhtrang$ echo "";

anhs-MBP:~ anhtrang$ echo "ISO version";
ISO version
anhs-MBP:~ anhtrang$ grep -i ISO ~/.minikube/machines/minikube/config.json
        "Boot2DockerURL": "file:///Users/anhtrang/.minikube/cache/iso/minikube-v0.26.0.iso",
```

Got following error:

```
nhs-MBP:~ anhtrang$ Starting local Kubernetes v1.10.0 cluster...
-bash: Starting: command not found
anhs-MBP:~ anhtrang$ Starting VM...
-bash: Starting: command not found
anhs-MBP:~ anhtrang$ E0420 08:24:57.963653   81977 start.go:159] Error starting host: Temporary Error: Error configuring auth on host: OS type not recognized.
```

Please advise

Answer (score 8):

[Minikube](https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/minikube/) is a tool that makes it easy to run [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/) locally. Minikube runs a single-node Kubernetes cluster inside a VM on your laptop for users looking to try out Kubernetes or develop with it day-to-day.

Let’s start with some pre-installation checks:

- do you have Docker containers installed? Please check it by executing the below command:

docker version

If it’s not installed or is outdated - Docker installation guide will help you:
https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/install/

- do you have any of the supported virtualization software installed?

At this moment, minikube can use these virtualization solutions to spin up all-in-one cluster:

- xhyve
- VirtualBox
- hyperkit

In this installation, we use hyperkit, because xhyve is deprecated. You can choose
VirtualBox as well, but I will not describe it here and focus on hyperkit.

Paste the following command in a terminal window:

```
curl -Lo minikube https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/releases/v0.26.1/minikube-darwin-amd64 && chmod +x minikube && sudo mv minikube /usr/local/bin/
```

next install hyperkit:

```
curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/releases/latest/docker-machine-driver-hyperkit \
&& chmod +x docker-machine-driver-hyperkit \
&& sudo mv docker-machine-driver-hyperkit /usr/local/bin/ \
&& sudo chown root:wheel /usr/local/bin/docker-machine-driver-hyperkit \
&& sudo chmod u+s /usr/local/bin/docker-machine-driver-hyperkit
```

At this point, please consider removing failed minikube installation :

```
minikube delete
```

Now you are ready to get started with minikube!

```
minikube --vm-driver=hyperkit start
```

After a while, the cluster is started, and you can use it by the command:

```
kubectl
```

Comment: thanks for comprehensive guild line,  I am able to fix it by upgrading to Mac os version to High Sierra  version, then do following command:

``minikube delete`` -- to clean up previous setup of minikube
``minikube star``t --  to start fresh one.

Comment: I was getting a Segment Fault 11 error every time I typed any command for minikube (ie: minikube version, etc). I was trying to find a way to uninstall minikube and hitting a wall. This answer proved to be what I needed to fix my failed install of minikube.  This worked perfectly. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

minikube `delete` and `start` will solve the issues

```
minikube delete
minikube start
```

[image]

for unavoidable situations, try uninstall and re-install minikube

```
brew cask uninstall minikube
brew cask install minikube
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using below commands for installing `minikube` on mac

```
brew install minikube
brew link minikube
```